# debug the last sentence of a program

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, debugging

I have used Eclipse and VS. When I insert a breakpoint and debug the program, it will stop before the breakpoint.

But what if I want to debug the effect of the last sentence of the program? Inserting a meaningless sentence(say `print 'pause'` in Python) is OK but seems awkward. Is there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio you can put break point on closing bracket in `main` (or any) method of `Program` (or any) class (default naming, may vary), then debugger stops just before closing application.

[image: break point example]

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason not to use a breakpoint on the last statement, like you said, then manually proceed one step? Depending on the debugger, this can also be automated. In GDB, one can use `commands N`, where N is the breakpoint number, to set a list of (debugger) commands to be executed immediately after a breakpoint is hit.